# Requests on an external API with from Django Channels

Tags: python, django, python-requests, django-channels

I would like to make calls to an external API from my websocket consumers (asynchronous).

I thought about using `requests` but it is synchronous.

Would that work? Is there another way to deal with that?

Answer (score 0):

aiohttp is a good option instead of requests https://aiohttp.readthedocs.io/en/stable/